# Navigating back after following link in iBooks

Tags: ipad, books

I was reading a book in iBooks and clicked on a link in the text which took me to the index at the end of the book. Is there any way I can get back to where I was reading before I tapped on the link (without manually flipping through the pages/table of contents)?  There's no obvious back button that I can see.

I'm using iBooks 1.5, which I believe is currently the latest version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you touch the middle of the screen to show the buttons and controls, there should be a text link at the bottom left saying "Back to p. ###". It is beneath the dots and the slider to scroll quickly through the book. Touch it and you'll be back where you came from.

Comment: Thanks Lizzan, my wife's an avid iBook reader and didn't know this and she's glad to know if now.

Comment: It *is* fairly hard to discover, took me a while too. Glad I could help!

Comment: Does this work in the most recent versions of iOS too? I can't see the link to go back.

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino It does show up for me at least.

Comment: @Lizzan I can see it on a epub, but not on a pdf

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino I'd never tried it with a pdf so I don't know if it ever worked, but you're right, it doesn't seem to show up with them.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the short keys shows below:

go back: command + [

go forward: command + ]